# Time axis for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series (hourly) data, and I want to print selected period of that data. Let say I want to print a week worth of data from 01-Jan-2019 at 00:00 through 08-Jan-2019 at 00:00. I want the tick mark starts at 00:00 for 01-Jan-2019. But for reasons unknown to me, ggplot starts at 03:00. Am I missing something?

Here is a sample code to replicate the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
Sys.setenv( TZ = "GMT" )

datetime <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01", tz = "GMT"), length.out = 744, by = "hours")
random<- rnorm(744,100,20)

df <- data.frame(datetime,random)

time.start=as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
time.end=as.POSIXct("2019-01-08 00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

png(filename = "test_ggplot.png", width = 800, height = 600, units = "px", pointsize = 24 )
plot.random = ggplot() + 
 geom_line(data=df, aes(x=datetime, y=random)) + 
 scale_x_datetime(limits = c(time.start,time.end),
          breaks = date_breaks("12 hours"),
          labels = date_format("%H:%M\n%d-%b")
          )
plot.random
```

Here is the graph, showing the x-axis tick mark label starts at 03:00 instead of 00:00.

[image: example ggplot time axis problem]

Comment: I'm not sure why is not using the first value of the dataframe as the first value on the x-axis. But I found a easy solution. Create a sequence with the breaks you want ```seq<- seq(time.start, time.end, by = 60*60*12)``` and use this in the ```breaks``` option
```ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=df, aes(x=datetime, y=random)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(limits = c(time.start,time.end),
                   breaks = seq,
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M\n%d-%b"))```

Answer (score 3):

I would expect your limits input to work, it could be a bug. If I drop the `limits` argument and add `expand` it seems to do what you want:

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df %>% head(300), aes(x = datetime, y = random)) +
  scale_x_datetime(
    #limits = c(time.start, time.end),
    breaks = date_breaks("12 hours"),
    labels = date_format("%H:%M %d-%b"),
    expand = expand_scale(0)
  ) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The axis label calculations occur within `ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot`, which is part of the plot building process when a ggplot object is plotted / printed.

If we dig into the underlying code (this can be done in debug mode, by going down the rabbit hole from `ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot` to `layout$setup_panel_params` to `self$coord$setup_panel_params`), we can see that **axis labels / breaks are based on the axis limits *after* said limits have taken any expansion into account**.

This axis limits calculation is done within the following (un-exported) function from the ggplot2 package:

```
> ggplot2:::scale_range
function (scale, limits = NULL, expand = TRUE) 
{
    expansion <- if (expand) 
        expand_default(scale)
    else c(0, 0)
    if (is.null(limits)) {
        scale$dimension(expansion)
    }
    else {
        range <- range(scale$transform(limits))
        expand_range(range, expansion[1], expansion[2])
    }
}
```

Here, an expansion amount is added to the scale limits specified as `c(time.start, time.end)` in the code. The actual expansion amount depends on a combination of arguments:

**Case 1: if `expand` is TRUE**

The expansion amount depends on the default expansion associated with the scale, as calculated in `ggplot2:::expand_default`:

1. If the scale's expansion factor is specified, expansion amount takes on that vector of values;
2. Otherwise, expansion amount takes on the default `c(0, 0.6, 0, 0.6)` for a discrete scale, and `c(0.05, 0, 0.05, 0)` for a continuous scale.

**Case 2: if `expand` is FALSE**

The expansion amount is hard-coded to `c(0, 0)`.

Hence, to preserve the desired scale limits `c(time.start, time.end)` for axis break / label calculations, one of the following two criteria must be met:

1. The scale's expansion factor is specified as `c(0, 0)` (as per @yake84's answer);
2. The inputted value for `expand` is FALSE--this is taken from the `expand` parameter in the plot object's coordinate system (`coord_cartesian` by default).

In conclusion, either of the following will give you the same x-axis labels:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = datetime, y = random)) +
  # increase margin on the right to accommodate axis label right at the end
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5.5, 20, 5.5, 5.5), "pt")) 

# specify 0 expansion factor in scale
p +
  scale_x_datetime(limits = c(time.start, time.end),
                   breaks = date_breaks("12 hours"),
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M\n%d-%b"),
                   expand = c(0, 0))

# specify no expansion in coord (note this affects y-axis too)
p +
  scale_x_datetime(limits = c(time.start, time.end),
                   breaks = date_breaks("12 hours"),
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M\n%d-%b")) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image: plot comparisons]